# Open surjection and filterbases problem

Tags: general-topology

I have been struggling with the following problem.

Let $f: X \to Y$ be an open surjection. Prove that for each $x \in X$ and filterbase $\mathcal{B} \to f(x)$ there is a filterbase
  $\mathcal{U} \to x$ such that $f(\mathcal{U}) \vdash \mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{B} \vdash f(\mathcal{U})$

I tried the most straightforward filterbase $$\mathcal{U} = \{f^{-1}(B) \; | \; B \in \mathcal{B}\}$$
Does it works? I was able to prove everything except convergence to $x$, but I wasn't able
to find a counterexample either. If it works can you give me a tip on how to prove convergence?

Any help or tips would be appreciated. Thanks.

**Edit**
A filterbase $\mathcal{B}$ is subordinated to $\mathcal{U}$ denoted by 
$\mathcal{B} \vdash \mathcal{U}$ if $\forall U \in \mathcal{U}$ exists $B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $B \subseteq U$

Comment: You should explain the $\vdash$ notation.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks for pointing that out, sometimes I don't know what is the standard notation for some things.

Comment: $f$ is just open, not necessarily continuous? Where in your own try do you use openness of $f$?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma To prove that $\mathcal{U}$ defined as above is a filter base, and the two subordinated relationships, just surjectivity is needed. I was trying to use openness to prove convergence to $x$ by taking an open neighborhood $V$ of $x$, the looking at the open neighborhood $f(V)$ of $f(x)$, and trying to use convergence there to get an element such that $f^{-1}(B) \subseteq V$. But I'm thinking that might not be possible.

Comment: @alejopelaez Yes, we get $B \subset f[V]$, which gives us $f^{-1}[B] \subset f^{-1}[f[V]$, which can be quite a bit larger than $V$. What about taking all $O \cap f^{-1}[B]$ where $O$ ranges over open neighbourhoods of $x$, and $B$ over $\mathcal{B}$, this would force  convergence. And its images are $f[O] \cap B$, which looks ok.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I thought about that, but $O \cap f^{-1}(B)$ is not necessarily non emty. And even if I force it to be non emty, the intersection of two elements of that Type isnt necessarily non emtpty.

Comment: @alejopelaez For $O$ open around $x$, $f[O]$ is open so contains some $B$, which ensures $f^{-1}[B] \cap O$ is non-empty, so we just take all such sets that are non-empty and try to see if those are enough.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7487/discussion-between-henno-brandsma-and-alejopelaez)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claim: for every open set $O$ that contains $x$ and $B \in \mathcal{B}$, $f^{-1}[B] \cap O \neq \emptyset$.

Proof: $f[O]$ is an open neighbourhood of $f(x)$, as $f$ is open, so for some $B' \in \mathcal{B}$ we have $f[B'] \subset O$. As we have a filterbase, $B$ and $B'$ have a common refinement $B''$, with $B'' \subset B \cap B'$. Then for any $y \in B''$, $y \in B' \subset f[O]$, so $y = f(x)$ for some $x \in O$. As $f(x) \in B'' \subset B$, $x$ witnesses the required non-emptyness.

Now $\mathcal{U} = \left\{ O \cap f^{-1}[B] : O \mbox{ open and contains } x, B \in \mathcal{B} \right\}$ I think will work as the required filterbase.

Being a filterbase is easy to check (the non-emptyness of the elements was the claim). For every $B$, $f^{-1}[B] \in \mathcal{U}$ and its image is $B$, which proves one subordination, and $f[ O \cap f^{-1}[B] ] \subset f[O] \cap B $, which contains $B$, which proves the other one. Also, almost by definition $\mathcal{U} \rightarrow x$.